# Firebase Dynamic Links Subdomain for Custom Domain

Tags: android, html, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to use Firebase Dynamic Links to have my users join a game group created by another user in my Android Application.
I got my custom domain and hosted my static site in the same project for my android application.
The issue for me is that I had understood that all my websites had to have `index.html` as entry point to my site, I really didn't know that I could name it at will nor know of the consequences of naming it differently.
Added a subdomain to follow the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#priority_order) to use my subdomain. When trying to set up the Dynamic Links from the Firebase Console I couldn't make it work getting this error in the console.

[image]

<s>Until I renamed my `index.html` to `start.html` as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550929/5482999).
I know only the basics on building websites, just to fulfill my needs, moving forward I'd like to understand why it works like this I literally use all **Develop** products from Firebase across my projects.</s>

If the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#priority_order) had pointed out the renaming of `index.html` could have saved me a few hours of frustration.

**UPDATE**
<s>So I renamed it to `home.html` and the site was not available anymore, then I renamed it to `start.html` and the site is ok again.</s>
Renaming the `index.html`, just rendered my site out of reach. Thought it was ok because I was just refreshing the site, when I tried in different browsers, turned out to be unavailable.

This is my Namecheap Host Records

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @cocacrave, no in the end I moved it to GAE and the subdomain has been registered but haven't had time to move forward on that project.

Comment: No problem, I found a solution that works for me. I was using a custom domain (example.com), then I registered another website under same project and connected a subdomain (sub.example.com) just for the dynamic links. Then in the cli for the subdomain, I added `"*"` to `ignore` which ignores the public from deployment for the subdomain target which got me past the red flag you and I are facing. I posted my question then answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703337/firebase-dynamic-links-subdomain-config/60705282#60705282