# Firebase Dynamic Links subdomain config

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

Let's say I have a domain `example.com`. And I created a second website through hosting and cli as `sub.example.com`.

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "app",
      "public": "public",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "promos",
      "public": "public",
      "appAssociation": "AUTO",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "dynamicLinks": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when I go to create Dynamic Link for `sub.example.com` without any path prefix, it gives me a red flag saying:

```
It looks like you already have content served on this path. Specify a different path prefix to avoid conflicts with existing content.
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Also, if this subdomain is only for links, I still have to put `public` field? I don't want to show anything on it, just links...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed it by adding (or rather ignoring) the public folder for the dynamic links subdomain.

```
"ignore": [
    "*"
  ],
```

I saw this post: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/566 and someone asked similar question for functions and the answer was to delete `dist/index.html`. But since my actual site depends on it, I tried just ignoring it and it seems to work.

Comment: This sounds pretty weird. the "ignore" clause just prevents certain local files from being uploaded at deployment. You just need to put the rewrite rule with "dynamicLinks" before the other (more general) rules.

Comment: This answer saved my day ! Thanks brother

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the same issue with @cocacrave's answer. Just sharing the full `firebase.json` file. * There should be a public folder and settings but my public folder is empty.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "*"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer saved my day ! Thanks brother

Comment: could we delete "public" altogether and get the same result?"