# Firebase Dynamic Links: Can't use Google-provided hostname

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I can't seem to set up **Firebase > Dynamic** Links using the Google-provided domain *'[my-app-name].page.link'*.

I'm trying to use **Firebase > Dynamic Links** for the first time so that I can use email-address-only authentication in my React Native app. I don't want to pay for a custom domain just to set up a TXT record so that Google can verify the domain, so I'd like to use the Google-provided domain name.

The problem I have with that is when I go to `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/[my-app-id]/durablelinks`, click on the 'Get Started' button, select the Google-provided '[my-app-name].page.link', and click 'Continue' I get the error:

```
This name is unable to be used by anyone. If you believe this is a mistake please reach out to support.
```

And looking for support led me here.

How can I use '[my-app-name].page.link' as my Dynamic Link so that I can pass dynamicLinkDomain to auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail and get the password-less authentication working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but it seems that the answer you're looking for is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174935/unable-to-add-firebase-dynamic-links-to-a-project-using-a-custom-domain) answered by [Jeff Avis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11209105/jeff-avis).

In short: type in anything.page.link and firebase will verify if it's valid or not.

It seems that the problem you're facing is that you've already used the domain you are trying to reuse, and deleted it! that's why it's blocked by firebase for the time being at least.